# Unknown Author error while deployment in .net MAUI Win App

Tags: c#, .net, windows, deployment, maui

I have developed an app in .net Maui and would now like to hand it over to my customers. The only problem is that the company's laptops only allow apps to be installed that are from trustworthy authors. Even if I create an author certificate in visual studio and install it manually on a customer's laptop, the author (me) is still not recognized during the installation (Errorcode 0x800B010A). Is there a way to fix this error?

Tried to create a certificate manually and installed it.

Comment: You need to buy a certificate from a recognized authority.  A self-signed cert is generally only good for testing

Comment: Where can i get one?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=buy+a+certificate

Comment: Was already solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75923100/how-to-side-load-onto-another-windows-machine-with-a-self-signed-net-maui-app